# Fixed table layout with auto width

Tags: css

According to spec, **Fixed table layout** won't work with `width` set to `auto`:

> 17.5.2.1 Fixed table layout
>
> With this (fast) algorithm, the horizontal layout of the table does
>   not depend on the contents of the cells; it only depends on the
>   table's width, the width of the columns, and borders or cell spacing.
>
> The table's width may be specified explicitly with the 'width'
>   property. A value of 'auto' (for both 'display: table' and 'display:
>   inline-table') means use the **automatic table layout** algorithm.
>   However, if the table is a block-level table ('display: table') in
>   normal flow, a UA may (**but does not have to**) …

Is there any hack to make it work anyway (using **pure CSS**)?

What I have: `table-layout: fixed` takes no effect with `width: auto`:

```css
table{
  /* those two won't work togheter */
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: auto;
}

td{
  /* pure visual purpose */
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Mid long text</td>
  <td>The very longest text</td>
  <td>Short</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to get: All table cells's width is set to the widest one:

```js
// width of widest table cell (in px)
var max = 0;

// get width of widest table cell (in px)
$('table td').each(function(){
 max = Math.max(max, $(this).width());
});

// set width of all cells to the width of widest one
$('table td').each(function(){
 $(this).css('width', max +'px');
});
```

```css
table{
  /* those two won't work togheter */
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: auto;
}

td{
  /* pure visual purpose */
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Mid long text</td>
  <td>The very longest text</td>
  <td>Short</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assign a percentage width to the `td` - you don't need any CSS rule for `table` itself then (see snippet)

```css
.container {
  background-color: #0fa;
  }
table {
  background-color: #fa0;
  }
td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Mid long text</td>
  <td>The very longest text</td>
  <td>Short</td>
 </tr>
</table>
  </div>
```

Comment: I want table cells to get width of the widest one, not a fixed width.

Comment: make the td width 33% then

Comment: Johannes I don't want a table to get width related to it's parent container.

Comment: It doesn't: I changed my snippet to have a 33% width for the TDs. Also I added background colors to table and container - there you can see that the table or td width is not relative to the container (otherwise the table would almost fill the container's width).

Comment: This seems ideal. It's not dynamic of course, but it seems to satisy the OP's requirements.

Comment: @Paulie_D it's even dynamic: if you put more text into the second TD, *all* TDs will expand. If you shorten it's text, all three will becaome narrower...

Comment: It's not dynamic to the number of cells is what I meant. This only works if there are 3 cells.

Comment: ah, okay. Yes, a different amount of cells would require another percentage value for TD width.

Comment: Beside the fact, it should be `calc(100% / 3)` not `33%`, and beside the fact that this won't work properly once amount of cells gets altered, this won't work at all if there is another table cell, without the `33%` rule (either [fixed](https://jsfiddle.net/v7u3ft44/) or [auto sized](https://jsfiddle.net/u9pk8fxj/)). In both cases, width will be related to table parent container, not the table widest cell.

Comment: But after all, thanks for pointing that out. I got rid of additional, fixed table cell, altering it with `::before` pseudoelement. Thanks. Upvoting and marking as resolved.